# openapi-generator-cli not generating documentation from PHP file

Tags: php, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator, swagger-php

Background: I have installed composer installed `zircote/swagger-php` and have installed `openapi-generator-cli` with apt-get.

I am not sure whether or not I am attempting to use these tools correctly, however I've been unable to find documentation pointing me in any direction.

I have a controller file with a whole bunch of code in it. I want to test whether or not I can generate a json file from it using open api annotation.

Here's a sample of my code (I've cut out unrelated chunks of it):

```
<?php

/**
 * @OA\Info(title="My First API", version="0.1")
 */
class Apiv1_LocationController extends App_Controller_API
{
    /* Publicly exposed attributes and the field type for filtering */
    protected $_exported = array('id','created','modified','name','address','phone','external_id','postcode','country','timezone','date_format','lacps','staff_count');
    protected $_schematypes = array(
        'string' => ['name','address','phone','external_id','postcode','country','timezone','date_format'],
        'int'    => ['id','staff_count'],
        'timestamp' => ['created','modified'],
        'complex'=> ['lacps'],
    );
    {more unrelated code...}

    /**
     * @OA\Get(
     *     path="/api/resource.json",
     *     @OA\Response(response="200", description="An example resource")
     * )
     */
    public function getAction()
    {
        {code inside action...}
    }
}
```

The cli command I use:

```
openapi-generator-cli generate -g php -i <path_to_LocationController>
```

I get the following error:

```
[main] INFO  o.o.c.ignore.CodegenIgnoreProcessor - No .openapi-generator-ignore file found.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Issues with the OpenAPI input. Possible causes: invalid/missing spec, malformed JSON/YAML files, etc.
```

This leads me to believe I am using the openapi-generator-cli tool incorrectly, since I wouldn't be expecting to need a JSON or YAML file, I am trying to generate that file.

I'll keep trying, but if someone could help me realized what I'm doing wrong or how I'm misunderstanding the tool, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I realized I'd been going about this in entirely the wrong way.

I used the zircote/swagger-php library to generate the JSON file I required with the following command (In the directory where I wanted the JSON to be generated):

```
./<path_to_vendor_directory>/vendor/zircote/swagger-php/bin/openapi --pattern "*Controller.php" --output <name_of_file>.json --format json <location_to_search_from_recursively>
```